# Python Pandas Cleaning columns with multiple dates

Tags: python, date, pandas

I have a dataframe with a column looking like this:

```
Event date
1/3/2013
11/01/2011-10/01/2012
11/01/2011-10/01/2012
11/01/2011-10/01/2012
10/01/2012 - 02/18/2013
2/12/2013
01/18/2013-01/23/2013
11/01/2012-01/19/2013
```

Is there a good way to separate the dates into two columns like

```
df['Start date']
df['end date']
```

where rows with single dates are start date by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use `Series.str.extract()` here to do this all in one fell swoop:

```
In [22]: df
Out[22]:
                event_date
0                 1/3/2013
1    11/01/2011-10/01/2012
2    11/01/2011-10/01/2012
3    11/01/2011-10/01/2012
4  10/01/2012 - 02/18/2013
5                2/12/2013
6    01/18/2013-01/23/2013
7    11/01/2012-01/19/2013

In [23]: df.event_date.str.extract(r'(?P<all>(?P<start>\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4})\s*-?\s*(?P<end>\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4})?)')
Out[23]:
                       all       start         end
0                 1/3/2013    1/3/2013         NaN
1    11/01/2011-10/01/2012  11/01/2011  10/01/2012
2    11/01/2011-10/01/2012  11/01/2011  10/01/2012
3    11/01/2011-10/01/2012  11/01/2011  10/01/2012
4  10/01/2012 - 02/18/2013  10/01/2012  02/18/2013
5                2/12/2013   2/12/2013         NaN
6    01/18/2013-01/23/2013  01/18/2013  01/23/2013
7    11/01/2012-01/19/2013  11/01/2012  01/19/2013
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like the following using the vectorized string `split`:

```
>>> df

                event_date  x
0                 1/3/2013  1
1    11/01/2011-10/01/2012  1
2    11/01/2011-10/01/2012  1
3    11/01/2011-10/01/2012  1
4  10/01/2012 - 02/18/2013  1
5                2/12/2013  1
6    01/18/2013-01/23/2013  1
7    11/01/2012-01/19/2013  1


>>> df['beg'] = df['event_date'].str.split('\s*-\s*').str[0]
>>> df['end'] = df['event_date'].str.split('\s*-\s*').str[1]
>>> df

                event_date  x         beg         end
0                 1/3/2013  1    1/3/2013         NaN
1    11/01/2011-10/01/2012  1  11/01/2011  10/01/2012
2    11/01/2011-10/01/2012  1  11/01/2011  10/01/2012
3    11/01/2011-10/01/2012  1  11/01/2011  10/01/2012
4  10/01/2012 - 02/18/2013  1  10/01/2012  02/18/2013
5                2/12/2013  1   2/12/2013         NaN
6    01/18/2013-01/23/2013  1  01/18/2013  01/23/2013
7    11/01/2012-01/19/2013  1  11/01/2012  01/19/2013
```

**Edit** As @DSM points out you could also do something like the following:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(df['event_date'].str.split('\s*-\s*').tolist(),
                  columns=['beg','end'])

          beg         end
0    1/3/2013        None
1  11/01/2011  10/01/2012
2  11/01/2011  10/01/2012
3  11/01/2011  10/01/2012
4  10/01/2012  02/18/2013
5   2/12/2013        None
6  01/18/2013  01/23/2013
7  11/01/2012  01/19/2013
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the `x` column?

Comment: Annoyingly the cleanest way I can think of to get a bunch of columns out after using `str.split` is something like `pd.DataFrame(df["Event date"].str.split("\s*-\s*").tolist())`.

Comment: No reason for the 'x' column. it's superfluous.

Comment: Yeah, I was going to add that as an alternative @DSM but then I didn't think it was any cleaner for this case. You're right though, if there are lots of resulting columns, that would be cleaner.